# How can I specify seperators using QDockWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qdockwidget

I have the following example code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.bgcolor = self.palette().color(self.backgroundRole()).name()

        self.central = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.central.setText('this is the central widget')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.setDockOptions(self.AnimatedDocks) #prevent tabbing

        self.rightDock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget('right dock', self)
        self.rightDock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.rightDock.setStyleSheet('QDockWidget::title{text-align:left;background:'+self.bgcolor+';}')

        self.everywhereDock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget('everywhere dock',self)
        self.everywhereDock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea | QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.everywhereDock.setFeatures(QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        self.everywhereDock.setStyleSheet('QDockWidget::title{text-align:left;background:'+self.bgcolor+';}')

        self.dockable = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.rightDock)
        self.dockable.setText('this is dockable only on the right')
        self.dockable2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.everywhereDock)
        self.dockable2.setText('this is dockable everywhere, also its not closable')

        self.rightDock.setWidget(self.dockable)
        self.everywhereDock.setWidget(self.dockable2)

        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.rightDock)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.everywhereDock)
        self.setTabPosition(QtCore.Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas, QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The question is how to insert icons, where the borders between DockWidgetAreas are draggable, so that the user has a hint, that there is this functionality.

To clarify: 
I want an icon between the black arrows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `QDockWidget` supports a "title widget" which is not a separator, but you can add it into every `QDockWidget` using [`QDockWidget::setTitleBarWidget(QWidget *widget)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget).

So you can create a generic `QWidget` to hold this icon using a `QHorizontalLayout` or something, and put it into the title bar. The default mouse events handled by Qt (such as the drag events) should continue to works normally and you have a customizable title bar.

```
self.rightDock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget('right dock', self)
self.rightDock.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

// add custom title widget
self.rightDock.setTitleBarWidget(self.titleWidget)
// add widget to dock widget
self.rightDock.setWidget(self.dockable)

self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.rightDock)
```

Comment: My question is about the borders between widgets, which are also draggable (like in a QSplitter), not about the headers. (see my edit)

Comment: @Jonas To insert any icon you must have a QWidget. I'm not sure if this "borders" has one, I'm guessing that you can't do it directly. If I find something I'll edit this answer. But until there, I would try to do something like subclassing the `QWidget` and whenever a `QDockWidgets` has been inserted to this `QWidget` (I'm sure there is a `signal` for that) you insert these icons manually.